# django celery 4 - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, django, request, task, celery

I have django 1.11.5 and celery 4.

I want to pass user in view to task (because I can't do this in tasks.py, right?)

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    dict_obj = model_to_dict(self.request.user)
    # serialized = json.dumps(dict_obj)
    # print(serialized)
    task_number_one.delay(dict_obj['username'])
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

In celery I got an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'my_username'
```

Comment: post your function definition of `task_number_one()`

Comment: Not sure your question, but you typically pass the primary key of a model instance you want celery to use and reload it from the DB in the celery task. Please update your question with your `tasks.py`

Answer (score 0):

What is the full definition of `task_number_one`? What is a full stack of the error?

Looks like the first argument passed to `task_number_one` is expected to be int, but the username is a string.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful for you to post the stack trace of your exception and a sample of your task, but with that in mind there's two places I would presume this error is occurring.

1. Your celery task is expecting the first argument to be an `int`, I find this somewhat unlikely.
2. Your celery task is searching for the user by their Primary-Key (which is most likely an int).

i.e.

```
def task(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
```

This would throw that value error if you pass a string into `user_id`.

You should update your view to use the `pk` or `id` property of the user.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    task_number_one.delay(self.request.user.pk)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```